# Downloading large files using XML HTTP Request

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a simple launcher for a game that can install and uninstall mods, and update them. I don't know a ton about VBScript, so I got most of the downloading/update code off of the internet. I have most of the code done, but I have a problem. I'm trying to download about a 1/2 GB large zip folder off of my google drive. It was working when all I had was a simple text file in the zip folder as a test, but all it did was download a corrupted zip folder. WinRar can't open it, giving the error message "The archive is in either unknown format or damaged". So my question is does the code that I'm using have a limit to the file size? I'm trying to download https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BxlXlAM9nwYTZTFUdXpWQlJyN2M which is a direct download link to my google drive file.

```
Dim http: Set http = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim stream: Set stream = createobject("Adodb.Stream")

http.Open "GET", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BxlXlAM9nwYTZTFUdXpWQlJyN2M", False
http.Send
With stream
  .Type = 1
  .Open
  .Write http.responseBody
  .SaveToFile "c:\updates\normaldata\normal.zip", 2
End With
```

Comment: " but it doesn't work"  tells us nothing.  Explain how it is not working.

Comment: What is the value of [`http.Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767681.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. It downloads a zip file, but I can't open it, giving the response of "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged" in WinRar. The value of http.Status is 200.

Comment: Can you show us a hexdump of the first couple bytes of the downloaded file? Does the downloaded file have the correct size?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353107/1630171) already pointed out your original link is being redirected to a confirmation page, because the file is too large to be scanned for malware. You need to extract the actual download link from that page, e.g. like this:

```
baseUrl = "https://drive.google.com"
url     = baseUrl & "/uc?export=download&id=0BxlXlAM9nwYTZTFUdXpWQlJyN2M"

Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.Send

If http.Status <> 200 Then
  WScript.Echo http.Status & " " & http.StatusText
  WScript.Quit 1
ElseIf Left(http.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"), 9) = "text/html" Then
  Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
  html.Write http.ResponseText
  Set dl = html.GetElementById("uc-download-link")
  http.Open "GET", Replace(dl.href, "about:", baseUrl), False
  http.Send
  ...
End If
```

However, when I tried to follow the link I got an access denied error, whereas the download worked fine in a browser. To make the VBScript work you may need to inspect the conversation between browser and the webserver (e.g. with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) and adjust the second HTTP request according to the results.

Answer (score 0):

First that link is not a direct download. It takes you to a page that warns you the zip can't be virus scanned by Google.

What you aren't doing is

1. Opening the file in notepad and seeing what it says. Zips start with PK, Executables and dlls with MZ, and you'll recognise HTML. You are downloading a web page that is under 1000 bytes.
2. You have no error checking. Note my code is 80% error checking.

> #define HTTP_STATUS_OK          200       // request completed

It gave you the page it wanted to give you.

This downloads a web page and saves it as a zip. Rename it html and open in internet explorer.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set ShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
On Error Resume Next
Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
File.Open "GET", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BxlXlAM9nwYTZTFUdXpWQlJyN2M", False
File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
File.Send
If err.number <> 0 then 
    wscript.echo "" 
    wscript.echo "Error getting file" 
    wscript.echo "==================" 
    wscript.echo "" 
    wscript.echo "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    wscript.echo "Source " & err.source 
    wscript.echo "" 
    wscript.echo "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    wscript.echo    File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo    File.ResponseBody
else
    On Error Goto 0
    wscript.echo "Server Response " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    wscript.echo    File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo    File.ResponseBody
    Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    BS.type = 1
    BS.open
    BS.Write File.ResponseBody
    BS.SaveToFile ShApp.Namespace(&h10).self.path & "\file.zip", 2
End If
```

Comment: Why not just check the `Content-Type` header in the response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131688/discussion-between-lankymart-and-noodles).

Comment: I tried using this, but I just get an error message 800A0BBC "Write to file failed". This happens whenever I try to download any file using this method, and I'm not sure why. I've heard it might be something with permissions, but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: You were told precisely your problem.